# Teradata excluding columns from select

Tags: teradata

I'm curious as to how you handle instances where users want to know how to exclude columns that have sensitive data. I know explicitly listing the columns is an option but what do you do when you have tables/views with 50-100+ columns?

Example: Say I have a customer table that has 50 columns, I want to exclude 15 columns from the select as they hold sensitive data. I'm aware of all sensitive columns as I have a separate view that specifies them, is there any options to using this view to dynamically define the columns to select?

Appreciate any suggestions!

One possible solution I looked into was creating violatile tables and dropping the sensitive columns.

Comment: Often we define views that either omit the sensitive columns or have some sort of CASE statement that determines whether the actual value is returned or some dummy / masked / encrypted value (perhaps based on account string, a join to a security table, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we actually grant access to sensitive columns using the CASE method you mentioned. We define 1 to 1 views on top of tables that joins some security table to determine if someone should see the sensitive columns. The problem is that when someone does have access to the sensitive columns but want to run queries that exclude them. @Fred